# Question with proving unboundedness in Linear Programming

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, proof

I would like to prove the following: "For a Linear Programming in standard form with constraint Ax = b and all variables >= 0 show that d is a direction of unboundedness if and only if Ad = 0 and all entries in d >= 0. Please help.

Comment: Think about what happens with `A(x+kd)` for `k >= 0`. Does this still remain equal to `b`? If yes, what does that say about `x+kd` ? Can `k` become arbitrarily higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend `Bertsekas - Introduction to Linear Optimization`, since it deals with Linear Programming in a graphical and intuitive way. It also contains the proof you seek.

A few hints:

- If `Ad = 0`, and `Ax = b`, then `A(x + td) = b` for `t >= 0`;
- Then, if `d >= 0`, what does this say about `x + td`? Does it ever become smaller than 0?

Now, the other way around:

- If `d` is a direction for unboundedness, what happens if any `d < 0`?
- Similarly, what happens if `Ad != 0`?